# I have an inner function that's always true, but when assigned to a variable in an outer function, its output is undefined

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm having an issue in some code so I broke it down to smaller test components to try to figure it out.

The goal is for `testOuter` to return the value of the `testInner` when `testInner` becomes assigned to a variable.

```
function testInner(){
    return true

}

function testOuter(){

  let y = function(){testInner()}

  console.log(y())
}
```

When I `console.log(testInner())`, the output is `true`.

When I run `testOuter()` the output of `console.log(y())` is `undefined`.

Why is `testInner()` losing its output value? I'm testing this because I'd like to be able to nest functions and have the outer function `return true` when the inner function is `true`

Comment: It's not `testInner` loosing its return value, it's `y` not having any `return` value.

Comment: let y = () => testInner()

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests that you think you are assigning the result of `testInner()` to a variable, when you are actually *calling* `testInner()` inside of a newly-defined function, `y()`

The `console.log(y())` in `testOuter()` is not returning `true` because the newly defined function `y()` is not returning anything. Since `y()` is not returning anything, the logged output of `y()` is `undefined`.

You can either give the function `y()` a returned value by writing:

```
let y = function(){return testInner()}
```

OR

You can define `y` as a variable instead of a function, setting `y` equal to the returned value of `testInner()`:

```
let y = testInner();
console.log(y);
```

### OPTION 1:

```
function testInner(){
  return true
}
function testOuter(){
  let y = function(){return testInner()}
  console.log(y());
}
console.log(testInner());
testOuter();
```

### OPTION 2:

```
function testInner(){
  return true
}
function testOuter(){
  let y = testInner();
  console.log(y);
}
console.log(testInner());
testOuter();
```

Comment: thank you! I think I have to use Option 1, because otherwise testInner() would evaluate before I want. My goal is to have testOuter create an event listener where y() is the function bound to the button, so it would only execute when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value:

```
let y = function(){return testInner()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing *function expressions* with *arrow functions*.

Any time you use the keyword `function`, you:

- Need curly brackets (ok, *should use*, not need)
- Need the `return` keyword if you want to return anything but `undefined`.

So your problem is arising because your function expression has no return statement. Thus the implicitly returned value is `undefined` as you saw. You could add that return statement, or use an arrow function.

Arrow functions *that contain only one statement*:

- May skip curly brackets, and if you do...
- Implicitly return the value of their statement

So you could also solve your problem like this:

```
let y = () => testInner()
```